# How to open a standby database (Oracle)

Tags: oracle10g, solaris-10

First, let me state that I am not a DBA nor am I a systems guy; I'm a software developer.

At work, we recently built a new virtualized db server by cloning our disaster recovery (DR) database server.  The DR database was kept in 'standby' mode (I think that's the correct term) and was synched with production daily.

So now, we have this new virtualized server that has a clone of that 'standby' database on it, and I need to 'open' that database so that it's usable (ie, no longer a standby db).  How do I do that?  We recently lost our DBA so this has fallen into my lap.

From searching the web, I've found all sorts of instructions.  It seems that I need to issue some commands via SQL*Plus?  But as what user?  From where do I issue these commands (I assume from the virtualized server)?  And what are the commands?

This is Oracle 10g v10.2.0.3.0 running on Solaris 10 for x86.